# how to allow some specific user/machine connect to a block port on production server via public internet?

Tags: networking, firewall

(I don't know if I am using the right tool for the job, but just try)

**My purpose:** Block access from internet on postgresql database port `5432` on production server. But allow some user/local machine to access this port from internet, **on port `5432` only**.

I tried some ways. Some works (but not effectively, in my opinion) and some doesn't.

1. SSH tunnel: tried and works. But I need to create a new user that cannot do anything on the server, except ssh tunnel to port `5432`. Let's try some other way.
2. Setup a VPN: did not try yet, but I think it works and there are many things to config for the user like case 1
3. Use firewall to allow connections from specific IP (my public IP): tried and work, but the downside is I have to ssh to the server and add new firewall config whenever my public IP changed, or I switch to another network.

**My questions:** What is the best/most efficient way to solve my need?

Answer (score 0):

1) or 2), depending on your needs. SSH is potentially very simple.

Don't use 3. You never want a database port directly exposed to the internet, even with firewall rules in place.